# SSRS 2005 report not working in SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a VB 2008 program that has a process that builds a list of transaction numbers into a String separated by a comma. It would then pass that variable to a SSRS report using Reporting services 2005.
My issue is now a customer has upgraded their database and reporting services to 2014.

When the report is called from the program now when the report starts to load I can see all the transactions number is the parameter box the report bombs.

I can open the report from the web and manually type one transaction number in, and then choose *view report* and it displays the correct data. However, once I type in 2 transaction numbers I get a syntax error display showing the syntax error occurred on the first transaction.

I believe that the fix has got to be somewhere in the Design of the report and setting up the parameters. I have checked *allow multi value* on the properties of the parameter.

This is not a use-case where you can just have the user run the report with one transaction ID at a time as they will not even know the transaction IDs at time of process.

The VB application pulls the IDs together based on closing of transaction requirements being met.

The report is a text based query using a `where` clause of

```
where TransID in (@Trans)
```

with `@Trans` being the list of transaction IDs. This is not calling a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Parameters tab of your dataset and check how @Trans parameter is set. It should be something like this:

```
=JOIN(Parameters!YourTransactionsParameterName.Value,",")
```

Comment: I had it as =parameters!yourtransactionsParameter.value and when I changed that to Join(parameters!YourTransActionParameterName.Value,",")

Comment: during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
The Value expression for the query parameter ‘Trans’ contains an error: Overload resolution failed because no Public 'Join' can be called with these arguments: 'Public Shared Function Join(SourceArray As String(), [Delimiter As String = ]) As String': Argument matching parameter 'SourceArray' cannot convert from 'String' to 'String()'. 'Public Shared Function Join(SourceArray As System.Object(), [Delimiter As String = ]) As String': Argument matching parameter 'SourceArray' cannot convert from 'String' to 'Object()'. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

Comment: This error message states that your parameter is not multivalue parameter. Multivalue parameter should be array of strings.

Comment: datatype is text. allow multiple values is checked on parameter properties

Comment: Hmm, if you selected parameter from suggestions in dialog window (not typed by yourself), then check if it is really `ParameterName.Value`? RB or VS designer by default paste ParameterName.Value(0).